# MIPS: the difference between the registers

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I'm learning MIPS assembly language right now and I still don't quite understand the difference between the following registers: **$at, $a, $t, $s, $v.**
More specifically, when should I use what

Comment: If you're not going to call (or be called) by any other code not written by you, then you can use them pretty much any way you like (`$ra` has a special purpose, and `$at` might be used by your assembler when implementing pseudo-instructions). If you _are_ going to interact with other code then you must follow whatever calling convention that code is using.

Answer (score 2):

Registers are use with respect to hardware or software conventions.

Some registers have a meaning hardwired in instruction set architecture. For instance, calling a function with `jal` will store return address in register `r31` (aka `$ra`). In a similar way `r0` (aka `$zero`) has a special meaning and always returns a 0. The behavior of these registers cannot be changed without modify hardware.

To insure a coherent behavior of the different software tools (compiler, asm, linker, loader, OS, ...), software conventions precise the role of some registers. These registers are completely similar in term of hardware, but software give them a specific role. These conventions can be changed without hardware modifications, but doing so will  require many changes in the software chain.

> I still don't quite understand the difference between the following registers: $at, $a, $t, $s, $v.

`$at` is "assembler temporary". It is used by the assembler to expand multi-instructions macros, and should not be used to store long terms values as these informations can be destroyed at any time by a macro call.

`$a0-3` are used to pass the first arguments of a function (the following arguments are in the stack).

`$v0-1` is used to return computed result of a function

`$t0-9` and `$s0-7` are general purpose registers that can be freely used in a program. The difference concerns their preservation across function calls.

`$t0-9` are temporaries volatile registers. They are supposed to never hold long term information and a callee function can use them without precaution. If the caller want to preserve some of them, it is its responsibility to save them before function call and to restore their value after function return. They are also called "caller-saved" registers.

`$v0-7` are temporaries non volatile registers. They are supposed to hold long term information and callees are not allowed to use any of them without saving its value in the stack and restoring it before function return. They are also called "callee-saved" registers.

If you are writing assembly function to learn MIPS, do not use $at, but for the other registers you can do what you want. But respecting these software conventions is essential when using compilers, linkers, etc; otherwise your code will probably not work.